# Angles and How they Correspond to Sides of a Triangle

Tags: triangles, angle

I have done some Googling but am not sure what question I need to ask. I came here instead.

I am at a 9th grade math level (Geometry) and working on a problem that is asking me to find *x* and *y* based on some sort of proportion that I don't know. That is my question. How can I find *x* and *y* in the problem below and what is the relation/formula used to determine the values?

[image]

Thanks much!

Comment: Googling the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) will be helpful.

Comment: You are welcome.